# Validate spaces using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to validate a field using regular expression as a data annotation. Suppose a user entered only spaces in a field need to alert a message something like "Spaces are not allowed". I'm using MVC4 and EF

Comment: It sounds like you want to reject inputs that consists of only whitespaces, but your error message that whitespaces aren't allowed at all. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\S]*$", ErrorMessage = "White space found")]
```

and then probably in the view you can alert the user.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for an HTML form, you can use simple HTML.

```
<form onsubmit="alert('checked');return false;">
    <input required pattern=".*\S+.*" title="This field is required">
    <input type="submit" value="check" />
</form>
```